# Construction of regular hypergraphs

Tags: algorithms, hypergraph

Is there any algorithm to generate $3$-uniform $k$-regular hypergraphs with $n$ vertices? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Generating them how?  Steiner triple systems are 3-uniform and regular, for an example.